# Laravel 4 Auth Filter: Unable to generate a URL for the named route as such route does not exist

Tags: authentication, laravel, laravel-4

I am trying to restrict a resource that I have named Artists (run by an ArtistsController).  I tried doing this directly with the constructor in the controller:

```
 public function __construct()
    {
    $this->beforeFilter('auth', array('except' => array()));
    }
```

And in my filters, I have:

```
Route::filter('auth', function()
{
    if (Auth::guest()) return Redirect::route('fans/landing');
});
```

In my routes, I have:

```
Route::get('fans/landing', array('uses' => 'FansController@getIndex'))->before('guest');
```

However, when I run this (trying to go to one of the resource pages), I get the following error:

```
Unable to generate a URL for the named route "fans/landing" as such route does not exist.
```

This is strange, because when I remove the construct function, the fans/landing page loads fine.  Also, it redirects another page (not part of the resource), fine to fans/landing, when I have:

```
Route::get('/fans/home', array('uses' => 'FansController@getHome'))->before('auth');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change

```
Route::get('fans/landing', array('uses' => 'FansController@getIndex'))->before('guest');
```

to

```
Route::get('fans/landing', array('as' => 'fans.landing', 'uses' => 'FansController@getIndex'))->before('guest');
```

and change

```
Route::filter('auth', function()
{
    if (Auth::guest()) return Redirect::route('fans/landing');
});
```

to

```
Route::filter('auth', function()
{
    if (Auth::guest()) return Redirect::route('fans.landing');
});
```